# Using $eq in aggregate project Spring Data equivalent

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Following is my MongoDB query which is

```
{$project:{
       firstName: "$firstName",
       lastName:"$lastName",
       email:"$email",
       company :"$organization.name",
       RoleName :"$organization.roles.roleName",
       matchingRole: { $eq: [ "$organization.roles.orgRoleId","$userOrgMap.roleId" ] }
      }
    },
    { $match: {matchingRole:true},{ $sort : { firstName : 1} }])
```

Following is my SpringData mongo API

```
aggregation = newAggregation(
                project("firstName", "lastName", "email")
                        .and("organization.name").as("company")
                        .and("organization.roles.roleName").as("roleName")
```

I want to know how to use $eq in project aggregate using Spring API. I tried to put the match outside the project as shown below. But query is not fetching mew any records. So I used $eq to compare in the project and assign the result in a new project attribute and check for it outside the project pipeline.

{ $match: {$organization.roles.orgRoleId","$userOrgMap.roleId"}

Comment: I have come up with the following equivalent                        
        project("_id", "login", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "deactivateFlag", "lastActivity")
      .and("organization.name").as("company")
      .and("organization.roles.roleName").as("roleName")
      .and(when(where("organization.roles.orgRoleId").is("userOrgMap.roleId")).then(true).otherwise(false)).as("matchingRoleIds"),
    match(Criteria.where("matchingRoleIds").is(true)),

Comment: Need to test this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$eq` aggregation the following way in `$project` stage.

```
and(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("organization.roles.orgRoleId").equalTo("us‌​erOrgMap.roleId")).as("matchingRole"),
```

Comment: It is giving me the following error  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property roles found on <<DTO>>.

Comment: The following works for me     .and(when(where("organization.roles.orgRoleId").is("userOrgMap.roleId")).then(true).otherwise(false)).as("matchingRoleIds")

Comment: You don't have  to use `AggregationExpression` to project values as `false` and `true`. That hook should only be used when the opeators are not covered in api. Use api helper `$eq` which returns boolean. Fix your dto include the roles attribute.

Comment: I am facing another problem. The MongoDB query works fine matchingRole: { $eq:[ "$organization.roles.orgRoleId","$userOrgMap.roleId" ] }
      }
    },
    { $match: {matchingRole:true}, But I am getting the following issue when I covert to SpringData API Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1309)

Comment: I am facing another problem. The MongoDB query works fine matchingRole: { $eq:[ "$organization.roles.orgRoleId","$userOrgMap.roleId" ] }
      }
    },
    { $match: {matchingRole:true}, But I am getting the following issue when I covert to SpringData API Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1309)    It is because of using the match criteria on the alias isMatchRoles.

Comment: Please consider creating a separate question with all the relevant details and data.The question to convert $eq in spring has been answered.  Its not recommended to discuss unrelated issues here. Appreciate your understanding.

Comment: Done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456910/using-match-on-a-variable-defined-using-project

Comment: Updated answer to use the aggregation equals operator. You can use the mongo template collection aggregate variant to bypass the type checking.Something like `AggregationResults<DTOType> results = mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, collectionname, DTOType.class);`