# Using conditional operator in a spring mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Following in my Mongo query

```
{$project:{
       id:"$_id",
       login:"$login",
       firstName: "$firstName",
       lastName:"$lastName",
       email:"$email",
       deactivateFlag:"$deactivateFlag",
       lastActivity:"$lastActivity",
       company :"$organization.name",
       RoleName :"$organization.roles.roleName",
       isMatchingRoles: { $eq: [ "$organization.roles.orgRoleId","$userOrgMap.roleId" ] }
      }
    },
    { $match: {isMatchingRoles:true},
```

This works perfectly fine. Particularly the last $match works perfectly to reduce the duplicates. But when I tried to convert the above code to Spring data equivalent, I am facing the following problem.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:‌​1309)
```

Following is my Spring Data code. I printed the raw output and happen to get boolean value for isMatchingRoles which is part of my bean class which is mapped during aggregation. But when the Boolean values is getting mapped using getMappedResult , I am getting this issue.

```
aggregation = newAggregation(
                        match(getUsersCriteria(searchTxt)), 
                        unwind("userOrgMap"),
                        lookup("organizations", "userOrgMap.orgId", "_id", "organization"),
                        unwind("organization"),
                        unwind("organization.roles"),
    project("userId", "login", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "deactivateFlag", "lastActivity")
                                .and("organization.name").as("companyName")
                                .and("organization.roles.roleName").as("roleName")
                                .and(when(where("organization.roles.orgRoleId").is("userOrgMap.roleId")).then(true).otherwise(false)).as("isMatchingRoles"),
                            match(Criteria.where("isMatchingRoles").is(true))

    AggregationResults<UserDTO> groupResults groupResults = mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, UserDTO.class, UserDTO.class);
                    System.out.println(" Raw result "+groupResults.getMappedResults().get(0));
                    // The above result is getting data properly for isMatchingRoles

                    List<UserDTO> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
                      // I am getting the exception in the above code

                    System.out.println(" actual mapped Reesult "+result.size());
```

Following is my input class

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserDTO {



    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String login;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String lastActivity;
    private String email;
    private boolean deactivateFlag;
    private String companyName;
    private String roleName;
    private boolean isMatchingRoles;



    public UserDTO(String userId, String login, String firstName, String lastName, String lastActivity, String email,
            boolean deactivateFlag, String companyName, String roleName, boolean isMatchingRoles) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.login = login;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.lastActivity = lastActivity;
        this.email = email;
        this.deactivateFlag = deactivateFlag;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.isMatchingRoles = isMatchingRoles;
    }


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }


    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }


    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getLastActivity() {
        return lastActivity;
    }


    public void setLastActivity(String lastActivity) {
        this.lastActivity = lastActivity;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public boolean isDeactivateFlag() {
        return deactivateFlag;
    }


    public void setDeactivateFlag(boolean deactivateFlag) {
        this.deactivateFlag = deactivateFlag;
    }


    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }


    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }


    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }


    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }


    public boolean isMatchingRoles() {
        return isMatchingRoles;
    }


    public void setMatchingRoles(boolean isMatchingRoles) {
        this.isMatchingRoles = isMatchingRoles;
    }



}
```

Following is my sample collection

```
user collection


{
    "_id" : "123",
    "login" : "abc@abc.com",
    "firstName" : "xxx",
    "lastName" : "yyy",
    "email" : "abc@abc.com",
    "deactivateFlag" : false,
    "userOrgMap" : [
        {
            "orgId" : "999",
            "roleId" : "888"
        }
    ]
}


Organization collection


{
    "_id" : "999",
    "name" : "orgName",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "orgRoleId" : "888",
            "roleName" : "Standard User"
        },
        {
            "orgRoleId" : "777",
            "roleName" : "Company Administrator"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Add both the input & output class to the post. Also the code where you are using getMappedResult method

Comment: done. Please check

Comment: Where are fields for `organization` and `roles` defined in `UserDTO` ?

Comment: I have provided the complete API above. Organizations is another collection which I lookup. Ogranization is an array created through that lookup.

Comment: You have to provide a little bit more details for reproducing the issue at my end. I would recommend adding test data from all your collections and updated `UserDTO` with `organization` and `roles` field.

Comment: Appreciate your help. As I had mentioned in my earlier comments, organization is not part of UserDTO. Rather it is an temp array resulted due to lookup with the organizations collection. Also roles is not part of the UserDTO. Roles is an array inside Organizations collection Organization is a array representation of organizations collection which has roles. I will soon provide test data.

Comment: done. I have updated with necessary details

Comment: You are welcome. Have you tried removing this line  `System.out.println(" Raw result "+groupResults.getMappedResults().get(0));` ? This will throw the posted error when the results are empty.

Comment: You are right. I am getting exception because of the System.out.println. The root cause of the problem is that the value for "isMatchingRoles" is always false due to which the last match pipeline is filtering out all false records which results in empty record. The root cause is that the line .and(when(where("organization.roles.orgRoleId").is("userOrgMap.roleId")).then(true).otherwise(false)).as("isMatchingRoles"), is not working as expected

Comment: I tried to use your answer which is to use eq as mentioned in your previous post. But I am getting the following error Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property roles found on com.abc.xxx.dto.UserDTO!

Comment: Now during mapping it is trying find roles inside UserDTO

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `(CriteriaDefinition)` api (not sure why is this exposed in projection, may be because aggregation operators does share some of its functions with query operators ) to generate the conditional expression, which should be used for regular query expressions( used in `$match` stage and regular find queries).

The criteria definition api generates the following query.

```
"isMatchingRoles": {
    "$cond": {
        "if": {
            "$eq": ["$organization.roles.orgRoleId", "userOrgMap.roleId"]
        },
        "then": true,
        "else": false
    }
}
```

Notice the second argument to the `$eq` is string value rather than field reference.

You can do it in following two ways.

Using `ConditonalOperator` api.

```
.and(when(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("organization.roles.orgRoleId").equalTo("userOrgMap.roleId")).then(true).otherwise(false)).as("isMatchingRoles")
```

Use `AggregationExpression` to generate the conditional expression.

```
and(new AggregationExpression() {
            @Override
            public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                return new BasicDBObject("$cond",
                        Arrays.<Object>asList(
                                new BasicDBObject("$eq", 
                                        Arrays.asList("$organization.roles.orgRoleId", "$userOrgMap.roleId")),
                                true,
                                false));
            }
 }).as("isMatchingRoles");
```