# Convert mongodb query using the mongo template aggregration framework

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Here is the query involving aggregation that is being used:

```
db.image.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: '$cameraId' , captured: {$sum: 1},
            singleFrameProcessed: {$sum: {$cond: ["$singleFrameProcessed", 1, 0]}},
            batchProcessed: {$sum: {$cond: ["$batchProcessed", 1, 0]}},
        }
    },
    {$project: {_id:0, cameraSource: "$_id", captured: 1, singleFrameProcessed: 1, batchProcessed: 1}}
])
```

The problem is not being able to convert to `mongo template` form using `aggregation`. Having problem with conditional.

My input (hundreds of document) of 1:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d29437e38cbf46b44f2e9f"),
    "guid" : "82057627-c4fd-4c10-9d43-f897491a3dc7",
    "filepath" : "FW-MD-1234",
    "insertTime" : NumberLong(1506972726974),
    "cameraId" : "1234",
    "computerId" : "FW-MD-PacoWork",
    "capturetime" : 1234,
    "iso" : 1234,
    "shutterspeed" : 1234.0,
    "aperature" : 1234.0,
    "singleFrameProcessTime" : 0,
    "singleFrameProcessor" : "",
    "singleFrameCollectionSetGuid" : "",
    "batchProcessTime" : 0,
    "batchProcessor" : "",
    "batchCollectionSetGuid" : "",
    "singleFrameProcessed" : false,
    "batchProcessed" : false
}
```

My output is summary of each camera:

```
{
    "captured" : 10.0,
    "singleFrameProcessed" : 4.0,
    "batchProcessed" : 3.0,
    "cameraSource" : "1234"
}    
/* 2 */
{
    "captured" : 11.0,
    "singleFrameProcessed" : 3.0,
    "batchProcessed" : 0.0,
    "cameraSource" : "052052001324"
}    
/* 3 */
{
    "captured" : 68527.0,
    "singleFrameProcessed" : 66297.0,
    "batchProcessed" : 925.0,
    "cameraSource" : "052052001304"
}
```

Comment: Please add inputs and desired outputs to this post.   It's entirely unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should add example input and output.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456910/using-conditional-operator-in-a-spring-mongo/44552376#44552376